# Including an Html page in a main html page - Javascript page is not working

Tags: javascript, html

In my project, which is a simple HTML/Javascript project. I am including pages into the index page for easier read-ability. This is a Tabbed page. So each Tab has a included html page.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Startup").load("Startup.html");
        $("#Continuous").load("Continuous.html");
    });
</script>
```

The Tabs look like this:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active" style="max-width:100%;">
    <div id="Startup"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="container tab-pane fade" style="max-width:100%;">
    <div id="Continuous"></div>
</div>
```

The issue that i am having is there are JavaScript files that are included in the Index page. 
The controls as i call them, on the included page do not work. Like it does not even see the JavaScript that is loaded.

I have not tried IFrames yet, however in the future i would like to be able to bring this up on an IPad and i do not think that is compatible or at least is hasn't been in the past.

All script includes and scripting are at the end of the page. I tried moving them to the "Head" section and it does not seem to matter.

My individual pages only have html required for the page so there is not Html, Head and body tags.

Is there something i am missing in these pages or is it just that including an html into another doesn't share resources? And if so is there a way to do this in another way?

Also it is worth saying that this needs to be staight HTML and there will not be server side scripting available.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

I am wondering if this is just a what gets loaded first problem.

I tried loading JQuery then my script above in the header and left the other scripts at the bottom of the page but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Load function of jQuery only loads data from the server (would need a URL to access this page). Load will not serve your local HTML file. As you told there is no server side scripting, load will not work here.

Comment: So i am using localhost on my PC the pages load but it does not seem to use the javascript files included in the main page. Even though they are part of the page according to the console in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding jquery to your page.  Something like this should work. Make sure the files are being served from webserver. You can't just open the index.html file locally in your browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Startup").load("Startup.html");
        $("#Continuous").load("Continuous.html");

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active" style="max-width:100%;">
    <div id="Startup"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="container tab-pane fade" style="max-width:100%;">
    <div id="Continuous"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll get CORS errors if you try to make AJAX calls from a local file. These show up in the developer tools console and look like this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/peterg/tmp/Startup.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, https.
```

You can use .load() to add html or text to an existing page. It's not a good way to include javascript. See https://api.jquery.com/load/

"When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded."

It does this to reduce the potential for [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

Comment: Sorry but the down vote was not from me! I really don't like to see anyone getting down voted..

Comment: Just re-tested the code I posted. It does work but you need to serve the page from a webserver. You can't just open it as a file. You'll get a CORS error if you do

Comment: Mine also works it just doesn't use the javascript files in the main page. So the control on the added page needs the additional javascript pages to work. In other words I have a functions.js and a objects.js that are loaded on the index page. The page that is loaded doesn't seem to see the scripts or visa-versa. Like it is treating it as a seperate page with no code on it, which it is but is loaded on the main index page that has the code. I am using localhost. It works but the external javascript pages dont unless i put it directly on the page without loading it.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work via ajax for security reasons.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think the issue you are seeing is intended behavior for jQuery.load()

Comment: @ScottPurtan did this solve or (at least explain) your problem?